# How do I calculate Survival Rate in SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

(Dialect can be `Vertica`, `Impala` or `Databricks`)

I'm trying to calculate day-0, day-1...up to day-7 survival rate for users. I'll treat all users for a certain date as d0 (regardless whether they are new or old), and look at how many of them come back at d1, d2, etc. Imagine we have the following data:

```
user | login_date
-----------------
001  | 2019-11-01
002  | 2019-11-01
003  | 2019-11-01
004  | 2019-11-01
005  | 2019-11-01
001  | 2019-11-02
003  | 2019-11-02
004  | 2019-11-02
006  | 2019-11-02
007  | 2019-11-02
002  | 2019-11-03
003  | 2019-11-03
004  | 2019-11-03
005  | 2019-11-03
008  | 2019-11-03
001  | 2019-11-04
002  | 2019-11-04
006  | 2019-11-04
007  | 2019-11-04
009  | 2019-11-04
```

And I'd like to see something like this:

```
date      |d0 |d1 |d2 |d3
--------------------------
2019-11-01| 5 | 3 | 4 | 2
2019-11-02| 5 | 2 | 3 | 
2019-11-03| 5 | 1
2019-11-04| 5
```

So you can see that d0 is 5 (even if some users logged in before), and for example we have `001`, `003`, `004`, `006`, `007` on 2019-11-02, and 2 of them came back the next day.

Now I developed a query that is close to my target, but is not the same.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        user, 
        login_date,
        FIRST_VALUE(login_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY login_date) AS first_login_day,
        DATEDIFF(login_date, first_login_day) AS days_since_first_play
    FROM
        table
)
SELECT
    first_login_day,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_first_play = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS d7
FROM
    cte1
GROUP BY
    first_login_day
ORDER BY
    first_login_day
```

The problem with the query is that it **removes old players from the date I'm looking at**. For example, using the same data, because `001`, `003`, `004` already logged in on 2019-11-01, the `d0` value for 2019-11-02 would be 2 instead of 5. So this query only works if I'm looking at new users ONLY.

I'm wondering if I can alter the query to achieve I want? Thanks in advance~~

Comment: is this `sql-server`?

Comment: No vertica impala or databricks, I have access to all three and all have similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an admittedly ugly way of doing it. The idea is to mark each user_id if they are a returner on day plus one, day plus two, and so on, and then aggregate by login_date. Would love to see a much nicer way of doing this.

```
with offsets as (
select a.user_id
    , a.login_date
    , case when b.login_date is not null then 1 else 0 end day_plus_one
    , case when c.login_date is not null then 1 else 0 end day_plus_two
    , case when d.login_date is not null then 1 else 0 end day_plus_three
from table a
    left join table b
        on b.user_id = a.user_id
        and b.login_date  = a.login_date+1
    left join table c
        on c.user_id = a.user_id
        and c.login_date  = a.login_date+2
    left join table d
        on d.user_id = a.user_id
        and d.login_date  = a.login_date+3
order by a.user_id, a.login_date
)
select 
    login_date
    , count(distinct user_id) day_zero_logins
    , sum(day_plus_one) day_one_logins
    , sum(day_plus_two) day_two_logins
    , sum(day_plus_three) day_three_logins
from offsets
group by login_date
order by login_date
```

[image: verified that it works with OP sample data]

Answer (score 1):

A few self-left joins and distinct user counts would give that result.

```
SELECT t0.login_date,
COUNT(distinct t0.user) as d0,
COUNT(distinct t1.user) as d1,
COUNT(distinct t2.user) as d2,
COUNT(distinct t3.user) as d3
FROM table t0
LEFT JOIN table t1 
  ON t1.user = t0.user
 AND t1.login_date = t0.login_date + 1
LEFT JOIN table t2 
  ON t2.user = t0.user
 AND t2.login_date = t0.login_date + 2
LEFT JOIN table t3 
  ON t3.user = t0.user
 AND t3.login_date = t0.login_date + 3
GROUP BY t0.login_date
ORDER BY t0.login_date
```

But if the login_date need to connect?
Then simply change the JOIN criteria to this:

```
FROM table t0
LEFT JOIN table t1 
  ON t1.user = t0.user
 AND t1.login_date = t0.login_date + 1
LEFT JOIN table t2 
  ON t2.user = t1.user
 AND t2.login_date = t1.login_date + 1
LEFT JOIN table t3 
  ON t3.user = t2.user
 AND t3.login_date = t2.login_date + 1
```